# IE compatability issues in react app. scroll bar problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

i am building a react app for my client and i am having some compatibility issues with IE. My side bar works fine with chrome and all other browsers but with IE11, the scroll bar is interfering with the sidebar like this.
[image: Wrong sidebar]

in chrome, it works fine. it looks like this
[image: working sidebar]

any idea what i can do to solve this problem?
I am new to front end development so i haven't tried anything yet.

i will include the code sidebar if that helps.. here it is

```
    class SideCharmMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        document.body.classList.toggle('has-charm', true);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        document.body.classList.remove('has-charm');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="charm">
                <button type="button" className="toggle-charm" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                    <span className="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

css for the menu:

```
 body.has-charm {
  overflow-x: visible;
  padding-right:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the css:

```
body:{
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using react-custom-scrollbars, it's is "smartly" adding negative margin, so I did like this:

```
.here-your-selector {
        scrollbar-width: none;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        margin-right: 0 !important;
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;

        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```